# Making an Alien Blaster Game for python

Tags: python

Ok I'm trying to make a program where I have a certain health and ammo for the alien and the human. I need them to go ten rounds. I want them to go the ten rounds randomly. I'm new to python, so I have some of it figured out but I don't have all of it figured out. I need to know what exactly am I doing wrong and how to do it.

```
class Alien(object):
"""Time to shoot the Player"""
def __init__(self,name,health,ammo):
    self.name = name
    name = input("What would you like to name your Alien?:")
    self.health = 75
    self.ammo = 50

def _str_(self):
    return self.name

def blast(self,enemy):
   import random
   ammunition = random.randrange(5)
   if ammunition >2
       self.ammo(health)
       print(self.name,"has shot the Player.")
       print("He has",self.ammo,"ammo left.")
    elif self.ammo == 0:
        print(self.name,"is out of ammo.")

def health(self,health):
    import random
    shoot = random.randrange(10)
    if shoot > 5
        self.health(ammo)
    if self.health >0:
        print(self.name,"has been shot down. He has",self.health,"health left.")
    elif self.health == 0
        print("Im already dead. There's no way you can kill me again!!!")

class Player(object):
"""Time to shoot the Alien"""
def __init__(self,ammo,health,name):
    self.name = name
    name = input("What would you like to name your player?:")
    self.ammo = 50
    self.health = 75

def _str_(self):
    return self.name

def blast(self,enemy):
    import random
    ammunition = random.randrange(5)
    if ammuntion >2
        self.ammo(health)
           print (self.name,"has shot the alien.")
           print ("He has",self.ammo,"ammo left.")
        elif self.ammo == 0:
           print(self.name,"is out of ammo.")


def health(self,health):
    import random
    shoot = random.randrange(10)
    if shoot > 5
        self.health(ammo)
    if self.health >0:
        print(self.name,"has been wounded. He has",self.health,"health left.")
    elif self.health == 0:
        print("I'm already dead. There's no way you can kill me again!!!")
```

These are my two classes for it.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, for one thing your indentation is off in several places, but... what makes you think anything is wrong? Care to share the symptoms of wrongness?

Comment: `self.ammo` is an int so it is not callable like `self.ammo(health)`, you are missing many `:` at the end of your statements. `if ammuntion >2` should be `if ammunition > 2`. You pass in `ammo,health` in the init method `__init__(self,ammo,health,name):` but never initialise.

Comment: well it doesn't run like it's supposed to and I don't know what exactly to do, to make it run the way I want it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i know what you are looking for. I remember writing a similar program for my sophomore school year and hope this helps.

```
class Player(object):
    """ A player in a shooter game. """

    def __init__(self,ammo):
        self.ammo = ammo
        self.lose = False

    def blast(self, enemy):
        if self.lose:
            print "You were unsuccessful and did not kill the alien!\nNow the Earth was destroyed thanks to you."
        else:
            print "The player blasts an enemy."
            if self.ammo > 0:
                self.ammo -= 1
                print "Your ammunition count is reduced by 1."
                print "The alien took 1 damage! You've done it!\n"
                enemy.die()
            else:
                if enemy.health == 0:
                    print "They're already dead, yo."
                else:
                    self.lose = True
                    print "The alien has more health than you have ammo."
                    print "You run out of ammo and die!"

class Alien(object):
    """ An alien in a shooter game. """

    def __init__(self, health):
        self.health = health

    def die(self):
        if self.health > 1:
            self.health -= 1
            print "Is that all you've got??\n"
        elif self.health == 1:
            self.health -= 1
            print "Oh no im gonna die"
        else:
            print "The alien is already dead.  What you're doing is unneccessary."

# main
print "\tThe Death of an Alien\n"

#same health and ammo
print "\n-----You have 6 counts of ammo.-----"
print "-----The alien has 6 health.-----\n"
hero = Player(6)
invader = Alien(6)
for i in range(6):
    hero.blast(invader)

#lower health than ammo
print "\n-----You have 6 counts of ammo.-----"
print "-----The alien has 5 health.-----\n"
hero = Player(6)
invader = Alien(5)
for i in range(6):
    hero.blast(invader)

#lower ammo than health
print "\n-----You have 5 counts of ammo.-----"
print "-----The alien has 6 health.-----\n"
hero = Player(5)
invader = Alien(6)
for i in range(6):
    hero.blast(invader)

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Was yours in a module or that's just how it was?

Comment: This was a stand alone program. I am not sure I completely understand your question. What do you mean by "in a module"?

Comment: a module is importing two different programs together in one main program

Comment: You need to be way more clear in your question then. In that case, you could store the player object in 1 file then store the alien object in an another file and then import them onto a 3rd file which will have the main code.